# Rendering pivot attributes in a new line/column after a certain number of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pivot-table, pivottable.js

We are using [nicolaskruchten's pivottable library](https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable), and we would like to limit the number of attributes shown per line on the x or y axis so after a certain number of them, they can "jump" to a different line in case of axis x attributes or column in case of axis y attributes.

Another way to see this is to define a fixed width for the container header row so the attributes can go in multiple lines by default after loading a certain number of them.

Thank you all for the insight given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to accomplish a close look to what I originally wanted to, eg:

```
Attribute1 Attribute2 Attribute3 Attribute4 Attribute5 

Atrribute6 Attribute7 Attribute8 Attribute9 Attribute10
```

Just open the file pivot.css located usually in `app/css/pivottable` and set:

```
.pvtHorizList li { display: inline-block; }
```

This will establish a more strict width and height to let them take the space accordingly and jump to the next line when there is no more space left.

Hope this helps.